# iOS Development Profile

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

1.
Does a Development profile work only with one App
Or can a development profile work with many Apps

2.
If I use testFlight - do I need a development profile or a distribution profile.

3.
Why would a user need more than one certificate.  If I develop on machine A at work and then use machine B at work - do I need two certificates or two profiles or just one of each

Answer (score 3):

1. A profile can work with any number of apps, use a wildcard App Id.  (com.mycompany.*)
2. Distribution
3. I have many different certificates because I work for different clients and they want me to build apps for them, so I have multiple certificates. If you're just using two machines and want to share the certificates, use the Xcode Organizer to export your profile from one machine and import it on the other. This will transfer the private key, certificates and provisioning profiles.

Comment: Why would having different certificates for different clients be a desirable thing?

Comment: I need to sign the app with their certificate so it can be uploaded to the app store under their apple ID.